# Finding distinct field in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been working on the Stored Procedure and trying to get distinct DBNs depending on the latest CEPCertifiedNL. Right now the problem is if a DBN has a different NetworkLeader then school is displayed twice. I am not being able to figure it out how to get only 1 DBN even though the Network leader is different. Please see my stored proc below:

```
DECLARE @CEPDocuments TABLE(
        Id int,
        SchoolId int,
        Submitted char DEFAULT 'Y')

DECLARE @CEPReviewed TABLE(
        Id int,
        SchoolId int,
        Submitted char DEFAULT 'Y')

DECLARE @CEPDocuments TABLE(
        Id int,
        SchoolId int,
        Submitted char DEFAULT 'Y')

DECLARE @CEPReviewed TABLE(
        Id int,
        SchoolId int,
        Submitted char DEFAULT 'Y')

DECLARE @CEPCertifiedSup TABLE(
        Id int,
        SchoolId int,
        Submitted char DEFAULT 'Y',
        SupName varchar(255),
        Note nvarchar(max),
        CreationMethod_S nvarchar(1))


DECLARE @Invitations TABLE(
        dateAccepted datetime,
        SchoolId int)

DECLARE @Reviews TABLE(
        Id int,
        SchoolId int,
        Note nvarchar(max))

DECLARE @PLANDETAILS TABLE(
        SchoolId int,
        TemplateType varchar(10))

DECLARE @YEAR int
SET @YEAR = 2014

DECLARE @planIds TABLE(Id int);
INSERT INTO  @planIds( Id ) SELECT Id FROM Plans as p WHERE p.SchoolYear = @YEAR;

DECLARE @cepDocumentIds TABLE(Id int);
INSERT INTO @cepDocumentIds( Id ) 
SELECT d.Id FROM Documents as d 
    INNER JOIN Plans as p ON d.PlanId = p.Id 
    WHERE ( d.Name LIKE '% CEP' OR d.Name LIKE '%SCEP - F' OR d.Name LIKE '%SCEP - P') AND p.SchoolYear = @YEAR;


INSERT INTO @CEPDocuments (Id, SchoolId)
SELECT MAX(Id) as Id, SchoolId FROM DocumentFiles 
WHERE DocumentId in (SELECT * FROM @cepDocumentIds)
AND DateDeleted IS NULL 
GROUP BY SchoolId


INSERT INTO @CEPCertifiedSup (Id, SchoolId, SupName, Note,CreationMethod_S)
SELECT MAX(r.Id) as Id
    ,r.SchoolId
    ,p.FirstName + ' ' + P.LastName as 'FullName'
    ,r.Note
    ,r.CreationMethod
FROM Reviews r
INNER JOIN People p
    on r.PersonId = p.Id
WHERE
    r.PlanId in (5,6,7)
    AND r.Note LIKE 'Superintendent % certified%'
    AND r.CreationMethod in ('C','W')
    AND r.DocumentId IS NULL
GROUP BY r.SchoolId, p.LastName, P.FirstName,r.SchoolId,r.Note,r.CreationMethod


DECLARE @CEPCertifiedNL TABLE(
        Id int,
        SchoolId int,
        Submitted char DEFAULT 'Y',
        NLName varchar(255),
        Note nvarchar(max),
        CreationMethod_N nvarchar(1),
        DateCreated DateTime)
INSERT INTO @CEPCertifiedNL (Id, SchoolId, NLName,Note,CreationMethod_N,DateCreated)
SELECT MAX(r.Id) as Id
    ,r.SchoolId
    ,MAX(p.FirstName + ' ' + P.LastName) as 'FullName'
    ,r.Note
    ,r.CreationMethod
    , r.DateCreated 
FROM Reviews r
INNER JOIN People p
    on r.PersonId = p.Id
WHERE
    r.PlanId in (5,6,7)
    AND r.Note like 'Network Leader % approved %'
    AND r.CreationMethod in ('C','W')
    AND r.DocumentId IS NULL
    AND r.PersonId IS NOT NULL
    AND r.DateCreated IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY r.SchoolId,r.Note,r.CreationMethod,r.DateCreated

INSERT INTO @Invitations (dateAccepted, SchoolId)
SELECT MAX(dateAccepted) as Id, SchoolId FROM Invitations WHERE membertitle = 'principal'  GROUP BY SchoolId


INSERT INTO @Reviews (Id, SchoolId, Note)
select Id, SchoolId, Note FROM Reviews 
WHERE Id in (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Reviews WHERE StatusId = 6 and DocumentId in (27,32,36) GROUP BY SchoolId)

INSERT INTO @PLANDETAILS (SchoolId, TemplateType)
SELECT  SchoolId
        ,CASE WHEN (p.Name LIKE 'CEP%') THEN 'CEP'
        WHEN (p.Name LIKE 'SCEP - F%') THEN 'SCEP - F'
        ELSE 'SCEP - P' END as 'TemplateType' 
FROM    PlanDetails as pd
INNER JOIN Plans as p ON pd.PlanId = p.Id
WHERE   PlanId in (SELECT * FROM @planIds)


SELECT rp.Value AS DBN

    ,pd.TemplateType as '2014 Template Type'
    ,ISNULL(cep.Submitted,'N') AS 'Submitted'



    ,CASE WHEN cerNL.Submitted IS NOT NULL 
        THEN case cerNL.CreationMethod_N
                when 'W' then 'R'
                else 'Y'
            end
        ELSE 'N' END  as 'Certified By NL'
    ,cerNL.NLName as 'Certifying NL'

    ,CASE WHEN cerSup.Submitted IS NOT NULL 
        THEN case cerSup.CreationMethod_S
                when 'W' then 'R'
                else 'Y'
            end
        ELSE 'N' END  as 'Certified By Sup'

    ,cerSup.SupName as 'Sup Name'
    ,cerNL.Note as 'NL Feedback on SCEP/CEP'
    ,cerSup.Note as 'SUP Feedback on SCEP/CEP'
    ,cerNL.DateCreated as 'Date'
FROM Schools s
RIGHT JOIN @Invitations i ON i.SchoolId = s.id
LEFT JOIN ReferenceProperties rp ON rp.SchoolId = s.id
LEFT JOIN @CEPDocuments cep ON cep.SchoolId = s.id
LEFT JOIN @CEPCertifiedSup cerSup ON cerSup.SchoolId = s.id
LEFT JOIN @CEPCertifiedNL cerNL ON cerNL.SchoolId = s.id

LEFT JOIN @PLANDETAILS pd on s.Id = pd.SchoolId
WHERE 
    rp.PropertyName = 'DBN' AND
    rp.Value not like '00T%'
ORDER BY DBN
```

Please see the table below:

```
    DBN 2014 Template Type  Submitted   Certified By NL Certifying NL   Certified By Sup    Sup Name    NL Feedback on SCEP/CEP SUP Feedback on SCEP/CEP    Date
02M308  NULL    N   Y   Nancy Scala Y   Marisol Bradbury    Network Leader Nancy Scala approved 2013-2014 document. Superintendent Marisol Bradbury certified 2013-2014 document.   2014-01-13 15:08:43.260
02M312  NULL    N   Y   Nancy Scala Y   Mariano Guzman  Network Leader Nancy Scala approved 2013-2014 document. Superintendent Mariano Guzman certified 2013-2014 document. 2014-03-24 22:37:22.980
02M313  NULL    N   Y   Alison Sheehan  Y   Marisol Bradbury    Network Leader Alison Sheehan approved 2013-2014 document.  Superintendent Marisol Bradbury certified 2013-2014 document.   2014-01-12 21:40:41.570
02M313  NULL    N   Y   Alison Sheehan  Y   Marisol Bradbury    Network Leader Alison Sheehan approved 2013-2014 document.  Superintendent Marisol Bradbury certified 2013-2014 document.   2014-10-01 12:00:00.000
```

Comment: I assume this is sql server and not mysql? You should remove on of the tags as you can't be working in both at the same time.

Comment: It seems you have 2 rows per whatever this is. The only value that seems to change is the Date. Can you use aggregates here? Also, why do you need to insert everything into table variables in order to select it back out. Couldn't you just pull the data directly? maybe you have more in this procedure that you didn't post in which case it might be ok but table variables are not my first choice. They have a number of limitations that a temp table does not.

Comment: When inserting records into CEPCertifiedNL in the reviews table, try removing the group by on r.DateCreated and just get the max of it

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. i found the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127976/show-only-last-duplicates-in-access-query